# What is the verb for "apoplexy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

In the following sentence,

> He [the verb] apoplexy a few years back and was suffering from numbness on the left side of the body, hence the need for a cane to walk.

what is the appropriate verb for "apoplexy"? Is it "get" like some other diseases? I checked some online dictionaries but none of them has an example except for one that used "suffering" as an example which is not what I am after because I'm referring to the very moment that it happened.

Comment: 1. Your comment at Jasper Loy's answer should better be within the question. Please edit. 2. *suffer* can and is also used in the sense you mention. You *suffer* a stroke or *have* a heart-attack. 3. You certainly don't 'get' it in the sense of a disease, but you do 'get' in the sense you could say *Looking at it all, he got a heart attack!*, which is fine.

Comment: There's a technical meaning and an informal meaning. Informally it evokes having a fit or being in a rage.

Answer (score 3):

An apoplexy is typically not a long-standing medical concern so you don't really "get or "contract" apoplexy.

In your example I would go with:

> He experienced an apoplexy...

or

> He suffered an apoplexy...

Also, due to the ambiguity of apoplexy as a condition, medical staff generally refer to the part of the body concerned, as in "a pituitary apoplexy" for example.

Comment: +1 for *suffered* However, it is an event and therefore needs the indefinite article ***an***: *The bite worsened, then he suffered an apoplexy and lay in his bed without the power to speak.* (See OP's comment at Jasper Loy, though.)

Comment: Thanks, Kris.  I didn't realise it was an event.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Kris: After a conversation we had in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/conversation/had-got-apoplexy), I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> He was **struck by** apoplexy [...]

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with the problem, and I am not sure of the progress apoplexy makes in a human body, but you might be able to word **developed**:

> He developed apoplexy a few years back and was suffering from numbness on the left side of the body, hence the need for a cane to walk.

Alternatively, if you "catch" the ailment, you can use the word **contracted**:

> He contracted apoplexy a few years back and was suffering from numbness on the left side of the body, hence the need for a cane to walk.